# Por que no funciona este codigo en python? (deleters)

Tags: python

-No me agrada hacer este tipo de preguntas, sin embargo estoy algo corto de tiempo y me da bastante curiosidad el saber por que no funciona un codigo tan simple como este ...

```
class Persona:
    def __init__(self, nombre, apellido):
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.apellido = apellido
    @property
    def nombre_completo(self):
        return self.nombre.capitalize() + ' ' + self.apellido.capitalize()
    @nombre_completo.setter
    def nombre_completo(self, nuevo_nombre):
        nombre,apellido = nuevo_nombre.split(' ')
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.apellido = apellido
    @nombre_completo.deleter
    def nombre_completo(self):
        del self.nombre
        del self.apellido

persona_nueva = persona('Juan', 'Peres')
print(persona_nueva.nombre_completo)
persona.nombre_completo = 'Nelson Martinez'
print(persona_nueva.nombre_completo)
del persona_nueva.nombre_completo
```

-Devuelve (al menos en mi maquina con windows 10 y python 3.9.5) `AttributeError`, se debe a un problema en el `deleter` que no logro identificar ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En el código el `property.deleter` se ve que funciona con normalidad, el `AttributeError` te pasa por que estas llamando la propiedad `nombre_completo` desde la propia clase `Persona` (en este caso seria `persona` pero supuse que fue un error al copiar el código), simplemente cambia `Persona` por `persona_nueva` y te dará el resultado deseado:

```
class Persona:
    def __init__(self, nombre, apellido):
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.apellido = apellido
    @property
    def nombre_completo(self):
        return self.nombre.capitalize() + ' ' + self.apellido.capitalize()
    @nombre_completo.setter
    def nombre_completo(self, nuevo_nombre):
        nombre,apellido = nuevo_nombre.split(' ')
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.apellido = apellido
    @nombre_completo.deleter
    def nombre_completo(self):
        del self.nombre
        del self.apellido

persona_nueva = Persona('Juan', 'Peres') #Copiando el código me daba un error de nombre pues no tenia el mismo nombre de la clase.
print(persona_nueva.nombre_completo)
persona_nueva.nombre_completo = 'Nelson Martinez' #esta es la linea que te provocó el AttributeErrordonde anteriormente era "persona.nombre_completo"
print(persona_nueva.nombre_completo)
del persona_nueva.nombre_completo
```

Resultado:

```
Juan Peres
Nelson Martinez
>>>
```

Comment: Ciertamente, muchas gracias ...